# Неопределенное поведение json

Tags: python, json

Я написал программу на питоне с использованием json, которая перечисляет каждый position Y, и заменяет значения на 5. Вместо того что бы перечислить все position Y и заменить значение на 5, он просто делает файл пустым, стирает все данные, при чем ошибок компилятор не выдает ошибок

Вот код

```
import json

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/storage/emulated/0/Android/hypper maps/Saves/")
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  jn = f.read()
  dt = json.loads(jn)
  
i = 0

whl = True
while whl:
    i+=1
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        dt['props'][i]['position']['y'] = 5
        if i == 200:
            whl=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/storage/emulated/0/Android/hypper maps/Saves/")
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    jn = f.read()
    dt = json.loads(jn)

i = 0

whl = True
while whl:
    i+=1
    dt['props'][i]['position']['y'] = 5
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(dt, indent=2)) #эта строка нужна, но её не было
    if i == 200:
        whl=False
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему